# I want to get child key of object in angular2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Inside of education_qualification object random key generated I want to get that key, how it possible ? 
I have tried to update that key but I got only education_qualification not an inside key.

```
create(model, bankDetails, currentAddress, permanentAddress, education) {
const obj = this.employees.push(model);
obj.update({
    id: obj.key,
    bank_details: bankDetails,
    current_address: currentAddress,
    permanent_address: permanentAddress,
},
    (error) => {
        const edu = obj.child('/education_qualification/');
        for (let i = 0; i <= education.length; i++) {
            edu.push(education[i]);
             edu.update({  
                  id: edu.key,
            });
        }
    });
}
```

[image: I want key inside of education_qualification]

Comment: I can't understand what u want to say ?

Comment: yes I want to update only key after object pushed

Comment: see the pic I want to get key inside of education_qualification

Answer (score -1):

Push returns a database reference.

[Firebase push documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data)

This means to get the key you do the following:

```
create(model, bankDetails, currentAddress, permanentAddress, education) {
const obj = this.employees.push(model);
obj.update({
    id: obj.getKey(),
    bank_details: bankDetails,
    current_address: currentAddress,
    permanent_address: permanentAddress,
},
    (error) => {
        const edu = obj.child('/education_qualification/');
        for (let i = 0; i <= education.length; i++) {
            edu.push(education[i]);
             edu.update({  
                  id: edu.key,
            });
        }
    });
}
```